# Are locale or time-dependent questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Too localized: by population size instead of geographical area](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/too-localized-by-population-size-instead-of-geographical-area)

Should questions that depend on a specific location (continent, country, city) or time (anything that changes rapidly over time) be allowed? I'm specifically referring to questions about how much to charge or what a job market looks like.

Answer (score 6):

I would vote to allow such questions.

I would argue that the fact that posts have dates on them leave the post up to the discretion of the reader.

The fact that StackExchange sites are designed for quick answers means that questions will be answered in a timely fashion. As such, there will not be open ended $$ questions. Users use SO with judgement. It's either current or not.

The same thing is with tech.  Let's shut down SO because tech changes a few time s a year with Apple and faster/slower depending where you go.

EDIT:

Perhaps we should make a new site called SiliconValue.se specifically for project price haggling?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong about discussing rates *in general*, but the questions presented so far are too localized, and invite people to ask the same exact question over and over with only a substitution in location. That's unwieldy and unsustainable.

Comment: I think there's a difference between asking "where can I go to find recent information on rates for programmers located in X" versus "how much do programmers in X make?" - the first is acceptable, the second not so much (IMO).

Comment: Ok and Ok .I can't argue with you folks. You're technically right.

Comment: I also edited my "answer" to this question to include my comment.

Comment: #Mark_Trapp There may be legal issues discussing rates.  In the US.  IANAL.

Answer (score 3):

I was originally okay with it, but in the first hour of beta, there are three mostly-identical questions that deal with different locales:

- [Hourly Billing or per project? Rates in the US?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134/hourly-billing-or-per-project-rates-in-the-us)
- [Best country for getting a job](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118/best-country-for-getting-a-job)
- [Programmer's salary in UK](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19/programmers-salary-in-uk)

Unchecked, this could consume the site. I think these types of questions should be closed as **too localized**.

Comment: Well, that's because locales vary. Remember, SO is for programming questions. This is another topic which fits the bill of programmers.se

Comment: Within reason, though. If there's going to be several questions every hour asking the same exact thing but in different locations, all other questions tend to fall by the wayside. Programmers isn't *just* about finding rates.

Comment: True, but it can be somewhat about finding rates. If it wont feed me, why should I program for others? (I'll still do my own hobbyist stuff, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

I say no. I don't think any specific questions that depend on geographic location (country, state, city) or time should be allowed. We should try to capture things that are long-lasting and relevant to programmers everywhere. However, if someone is asking for a resource that helps them obtain geographic or time-specific information (such as asking for a website that regularly tracks salaries of programmers in country X), that should be acceptable.

I realize that some things will become irrelevant over the course of time, but specifically, things like the current job market and wages/rates change far too rapidly, IMO, to be of use here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm conflicted.  I see a few points to this:

- Some interesting and worthy questions may *require* local context (eg, "What's the average salary" is less useful than "What's the average salary in the UK?)
- Some similar questions would be clearly useless for too small of a Geographical area ("what's the average salary in the town of Warwick in Orange County, NY)
- The above two points would put us in the hairy position of deciding what constitutes "too small" (is Sri Lanka too small?  Latvia?  Italy?  France?)

Given that, I think it'd be better to avoid geographically local questions entirely, at the cost of whatever small amount of good discussion might have been had.