# Automatically marking questions as potentially localised?

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications

Would it be desirable for a message similar to the

> The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

notification to be displayed for this SE, while questions are being asked, based on certain geographical terms in the title or other metrics?

Answer (score 4):

The *too localized* question suffers from a bit of misuse due to a somewhat unclear description. "In New York" or "In the UK" wouldn't count as *too localized*, nor would most easily recognizable geographical names.

As [Joel Spolsky likes to phrase it](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/too-localized-by-population-size-instead-of-geographical-area/1916#1916):

> Classic example of too localized: "Why is there a Green Honda Civic parked on my block right now?" Or, "Has the latest version of OS-X shipped yet?"

In this case, the *too localized* parts of these questions are:

- "on my block right now"
- "latest version ... shipped yet"

Trying to detect a *too localized* question the same way *too subjective* questions are detected (keyword matching) would be difficult, if not impossible.