# Encouraging the "unpolished" question?

Tags: discussion, questions, quality, declined-flags

I'm not fond of calling users out, but with [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134702/how-should-i-design-my-rpn-calculator), I'm a bit confused.

It came across initially as fitting the "I'm question banned on SO, so I'm parking it here" category to be honest and frank.  I understand that it looks like it could be more of a conceptual question, but I think at the heart, it's looking for someone to code the majority of the procedures.  There was some great editing, and I agree that doing so gets it out of the irretrievable box a bit, but at what cost?

In the interest of transparency, I did flag this question, and the flag was rejected, so that's not the issue here.  I do wonder why it passed muster, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was the moderator who handled the flags on the question.  From what I can tell, he just needed a little bit of help to clarify that his question—while not great—is on-topic here. It didn't appear need a moderator to intervene at first blush.

When I looked at the flags, though, I saw:

- **too localized:** Well, it's not too localized. While it might not be a problem every single programmer faces, how to design an RPN calculator is applicable to more than just [a vanishingly small number of people](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1916/8).
- **off topic, belongs on Stack Overflow:** the guy's not asking about a coding issue but how to design the problem, and if it *is* a crappy question, migrating it to Stack Overflow goes against [the golden rule](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1901/8).
- **not a real question:** this one had the most merit, but given a quick edit cleared things up, it really didn't warrant bringing a moderator's attention to it.

While I suspect that the user is trying to do homework<sup>1</sup>, based on seeing the question and evaluating the flags raised, I disagree that the question is so irredeemable that it required the swift hand of justice.

That said, it's likely to be closed by the community anyway in short order.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: I suspect there's a bit of an inherent bias at play when people suspect that someone is trying to get homework help, but homework questions [shouldn't be discounted](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2895/8) or treated any differently than other questions.

Comment: When I said "calling out" I should have clarified that I meant drawing attention to the user who asked the question, not the mod who had handled it.

Comment: In terms of the actual "question", it asks: "How does the cursor go to to upper and lower lines?"  Given that the user is doing this one aspect of the question specifically in C# with a textbox (as specified in the tags), is not asking about a general methodology or hints about implementing one, and yet not specifying what facet of .NET they were using would seem to make any one of those 3 flags valid.  I grant you, perhaps it did not need moderator intervention, but expecting that an edit would do anything more than pave over the problem is optimistic.

Comment: @jonsca I understand: I tried to reword my answer to explain why I don't think the question (or the user) needs to be slapped; I didn't see anything looking at it myself or considering the flags that screamed "this question is complete garbage." Not great, yes; but not irredeemable. Which is why I (and I suspect svick) edited the question instead of closing it.

Comment: @jonsca Fair enough: it already has 4 close votes, and will likely be be closed anyway.

Comment: If there's any bias on my part, it's people (possibly) skirting question bans on SO.  I appreciate your answer here, your edit, and your effort in editing the question on the main site.

Comment: I think our edits and comments are all crossing each other, so I hear ya.

Comment: I read the question as "How do I do x in C#" which I read as an implementation problem; not a conceptual one. Now that it's not a wall of text; I can see it's a skeletal design question with so little detail that it can't be answered effectively. I still vote to close it just for being too vague rather than OT.

Comment: I think you've violated the so-called golden rule. This question shouldn't have been migrated to SO. There is nowhere near enough information provided to make it answerable.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't migrate it: 4 regular people voted to migrate to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, pardon me then. I erroneously assumed you were the migrating party without actually checking.